# How can i overcome frequent timeout error in StackExchange.Redis or use other component replace it?

Tags: .net, redis, stackexchange

What is the difference between StackExchange.Redis and Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis?

When I use StackExchange.Redis as Redis component,we found there is much timeout error in concurrency environment.And it's hard to solve it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.